# Question about blocks and grand central dispatch

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

Ik have a question i cant find an answer to because i want to know if my current code is correct or not. The code is below.

The question is about the while loop.. is this correct ?

PS: Platinum uPnp needs a while loop after Start() or the process will stop apparently.

```
- (void) start {

 scan_queue = dispatch_queue_create("upnpscan.devices", NULL);

    dispatch_async(scan_queue, ^{

        PLT_CtrlPointReference ctrlPoint(new PLT_CtrlPoint());        
        BritneyMediaController controller(ctrlPoint, self);

        upnp.AddCtrlPoint(ctrlPoint);
        upnp.Start();

        [self setRunning:YES];
        while([self running]) { 

        }
        NSLog(@"Stopped running");
    });
    NSLog(@"Voor sleep");
    sleep(10);
    NSLog(@"Ik ben wakker");
    [self stop];
}

- (void) stop {

    [self setRunning:NO]; 
    return;

}
```

Comment: Note that mixing C++ and Blocks is rather fragile (i.e. completely broken, in some cases) outside of LLVM 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't look right. If you need the while loop, that implies that Start() is non-blocking, in which case it doesn't need to be in a background thread. You should run a runloop on the main thread and start from there, it looks like.

Comment: The thing is it could be non blocking and this indicates it is but if i dont do a while loop after the start() the build in socket listener stops listening.

Comment: i fixed it . It was stupid dont laugh. I did initialize the listening state with start() and then left the function so it would forget about the instance.